# Arduino pmos ZVP2106A as switch

Tags: arduino, switching, mosfet-driver, pmos

I've got some [ZVP201A](http://www.diodes.com/_files/datasheets/ZVP2106A.pdf) PMOS transistor and I want to use one as a switch to control a little 5V 110-150mA light bulb with an Arduino. Here is my schematic:
[image: ZVP201A switching]

Is it correct? Is the ZVP201A the right transistor for my application? The 10k pull down resistor is really needed? How can I choose the right value for the Gate resistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit looks fine to me, but I'm not sure about your choice of mosfet.

The pull-down resistor is optional, but recommended. If the Arduino is unconnected, or the I/O pin is configured as an input, the mosfet gate would be floating. This could cause it to be neither fully on nor fully off, and dissipate so much power it could be damaged. The pull-down resistor protects you from this.

As for the gate resistor, it is to limit the inrush current when switching, which can be significant. The Atmega328P has an absolute maximum rating of 40mA per I/O pin, so you'd want at least 125Ω, but a bit of a margin is a good idea. 150Ω would give you 33mA max, so you'd be safe.

If you want to switch quickly (e.g., using PWM), you want the gate resistor to be as small as possible. If you're only switching occasionally, then anything under 10kΩ is probably fine.

Now for the choice of mosfet. If you look at the third and fourth graphs in the datasheet, you can see that at -5V gate voltage, the Drain-Source voltage at 250mA is over 2V! At your desired 100mA, it's probably less, let's say 2V exactly. That leaves only 3V for your light. And these are *typical* values, they could be better, but also worse.

Even if you managed to turn that mosfet fully on, its Rdson is 5Ω, so that's at least 0.5V drop at 100mA. This mosfet might not work well for your purposes. If you look for another one, try to find one where the graphs say it'll comfortably do at your gate voltage.

You might consider a jelly-bean bipolar transistor instead. At those currents, those tend to have a voltage drop of 0.7V, but you're guaranteed to properly switch such a transistor.

Answer (score 0):

The gate resistor can be omitted completely, as the gate can be thought of abstractly as a capacitor in a FET; which is to say negligible (steady-state / DC) current will flow into it. The pull-down resistor can also be omitted as long as you don't mind what the thing does while your Arduino is starting up; which is to say it sets the "default" state of the FET to "on" absent the influence of Arduino software driving the pin high or low. The LED will turn on when the gate is low, and off when the gate is high. You'll still want to include a current limiting resistor in series with your load LED.

Comment: That is misleading; FET gate capacitance will sink/source significant current while switching. These peak currents can be orders of magnitude larger than the maximum I/O pin current. The gate resistor is not optional if you want to be sure your AVR lives.

Comment: Fair enough, but I think it will just current limit